# Where is the realtime msgstore.db for whatsapp?

Tags: whatsapp

I'm playing arround a little bit with [Decrypting whatasapp](https://github.com/ElDavoo/WhatsApp-Crypt14-Crypt15-Decrypter).

When I decrypt and open the sqlite3 that can be found `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Databases/msgstore.db.crypt15` I only see messages until last night. It seems that whatsapp is storing the messages until the night backup in other place. When the night backup occurs the `/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Databases/msgstore.db.crypt15` is updated. When I play with this file during the day it's never updated in my phone but whatsapp messages are coming in normally.

If having a look at the file:

```
actual date:     20230204 18:37:45
file created: 20230204 02:02:39
file modifyed:20230204 02:01:47
```

Answer (score 0):

Its inside data/data/com.whatsapp/database/msgstore.db
Need a Rooted device to get access. Or root adb.